# Elasticsearch Query match_all

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 1.5.2. I have an index with 278 stored products. I check that they are stored in head plugin. When Run a query of match_all I get only 10 hits however the total is 278. I get this result:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 278,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [.................only 10 products.......]
```

I want that I get in hits all my 278 results.

Comment: Use `size=278` in your query ;-)

Comment: like this?
 {
   "query": { 
        "match_all": { "size" : 278 }
                 
    }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in a `size` parameter to your query, like this:

```
 POST /_search
 {
  "from" : 0, "size" : 300,
  "query" : {
      "match_all":{}
   }
 }
```

The default is just 10 documents.

Comment: I get this error 

"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[V2Qrv7XXSWaHbis2wJ8_Rg][

Comment: It needs } at the end, and yes it works! , thank you.